# .Net Core 2 Accept Header of XML returning 406

Tags: xml, rest, api, asp.net-core-2.0, request-headers

I have added both an output formatted and an input formatted for xml for my API solution

```cs
//add formatter to support XML media type results(application/xml)
setupAction.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
//add formatter to support XML media type request(application/xml)
setupAction.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerInputFormatter());
```

but when I make a request using an accept header of application/xml I get a 406 has anyone else ran into this?

The content type is application/json

---- FIXED ----

If the object that the controller action returns has a constructor and the accept header is application/xml then the response will be a 406. Simply removed the constructor and then I could return XML.

Comment: some case  is that the controller have [Produces("application/json")]

Comment: in my case, XML serialization can't serialize an ICollection<>. Must be defined as a List<>. Weak sauce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

re. "If the object that the controller action returns has a constructor and the accept header is application/xml then the response will be a 406."  Actually, that's not correct.  Correction: "If the object that the controller action returns has a constructor **that takes arguments, and the object also has no 0-argument constructor,** and the accept header is application/xml then the response will be a 406."

Comment: What a joke 0.o

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue (.Net Core 2.2).

Because of the note on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I checked that my controller inherits from Controller and that my method was returning IActionResult. That was the case.

At first I added this output formatter:

```
  setupAction.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
```

That didn't work although the formatters was in the outputformatters list and with the correct MediaType.

Then I changed to using the preferred .Net 2.2 way:

```
        services.AddMvc(setupAction => 
        { 
               ...
        })
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Stil no success.

I went back to "old" way and removed AddXmlSerializerFormatters() and added

```
 setupAction.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
```

I.e. Using XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter instead of XmlSerializerOutputFormatter.

and then it worked.

I spend some time to figure out the differenced and my guess is that the XmlSerializerOutputFormatter can write the object type which is IEnumerable and Customer is a POCO without constructor.

This is what's in the log using  XmlSerializerOutputFormatter
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultOutputFormatterSelector:Warning: No output formatter was found for content type 'application/xml' to write the response.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor:Warning: No output formatter was found for content type 'application/xml' to write the response.

Comment: My class had an constructor with no argument but nothing worked except this `setupAction.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());`, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Actually, I had the same problem, In my case I have a relationship in my tables, so, Entity Framework create a IEnumerable<Class> when you have HasMany, so what I did was just change my code 
from:
public ICollection<Credential> Credential { get; set; }

to:
public List<Credential> Credential { get; set; }

and Constructor from:
        public Personal()
        {
            Credential = new HashSet<Credential>();
        }
to:
        public Personal()
        {
            Credential = new List<Credential>();
        }
```